# jsonapi-rb Relationships Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json-api

I'm trying to get a JSON which looks like such

```
{
   "data" : {
     "type": "field_definition",
     "id": 5,
     "attributes": {
        "specifier": "foo",
        "entity_type": "bar"
     }
     "relationships": {
        "active_collections" : [1,2,3]
     }
   }
}
```

I made a test class which Im using as my model:

```
  class Test
     attr_reader :id,
              :specifier,
              :entity_type,
              :active_collections

      def initialize
        @id = 5
        @specifier = "foo"
        @entity_type = "bar"
        @active_collections = [1,2,3]
      end
    end
```

My serializer:

```
class SerializableFieldCollection < JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource
  type 'field_collection'

  attributes :specifier, :entity_type

  has_many :active_collections 
end
```

I'm calling everything like

```
  def index
    render jsonapi: Test.new,
           class:   SerializableFieldCollection,
           status:  200   
  end


{"data"=>
  {"id"=>"5", "type"=>"field_collection", "attributes"=>{"specifier"=>"foo", "entity_type"=>"bar"}, "relationships"=>{"active_collections"=>{"meta"=>{"included"=>false}}}}}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction to how to use the relationships/has_many function in the jsonapi-rb gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I take it your question is about the `{"meta"=>{"included"=>false}}` part, that you would rather be `{"data"=>[{ "type": "foo", "id": "1" },{ "type": "foo", "id": "2" }, ...]}`?
If so, the default behavior is to serialize the linkage data for a relationship only when the relationship is included. In order to include a relationship in the response, use the `include` renderer option.

Example:

```
render jsonapi: Test.new,
       class:   SerializableFieldCollection,
       include: 'active_collections',
       status:  200
```

Comment: If you do want the linkage data w/o including the linked record, you can add `linkage always: true` to the relationship's block

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that `JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource` implements `ActiveModel` or `ActiveRecord`? If not, I don't think you can use a `has_many` here. Where is your definition for `ActiveCollection`?

Comment: I think `JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource` has its own impelementation not related to `ActiveRecord`? According to the documentation provided by `jsonapi-rails` `has_many` is the right thing to use

Comment: `has_many` is indeed part of the `JSONAPI::Serializable::Resource` DSL.